# Как просто реализовать горизонтальный скролл аля Google?

Tags: javascript, html, css

На левой картинке, категории поиска можно скроллить (WEB, IMGES,...).
[image: Как просто?]
Вопрос такой, как можно более просто реализовать такое у себя на странице?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй использовать свойство overflow. [Описание](http://htmlbook.ru/css/overflow)

```css
#parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: visible;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  border: 1px solid red;
  
  }

.ch {
  width: 440px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4; 
  }
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="ch">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, est cu labores meliore.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Кажется то, что искал