# Как сделать полосу прокрутки невидимой, но оставить скроллинг?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Update!** Это баг на ios, решения нету. На андроид все отлично. Спасибо. Работает самый первый вариант.

Собственно, уж очень понравилось сделать горизонтальную прокрутку как на *[Medium.com](https://medium.com/devschacht)* (на малых разрешениях), изящно. Все сделал, но есть полоса прокрутки, как сделать её невидимой?

Тот же вариант горизонтальной прокрутки на поисковике *[Google](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/490730/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F-google)*

Стили у блока прокрутки `div`:

```
-ms-overflow-style: none
overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none
overflow-x: scroll
overflow-y: hidden
&::-webkit-scrollbar
  width: 0 !important
  height: 0
  display: none !important
  background: transparent
```

Comment: какую горизонтальную прокрутку?

Comment: @ThisMan уже есть) Та дело не в стилизации, просто убрать саму полосу, но оставить скролл. На браузерах работает, а на смартфоне (iphone se) ни в какую.

Comment: @Predaytor нету никакой полосы прокрутки

Comment: @Избытоксусликов сразу внизу под глав. изображением - Node.js ХАРДКОР ...

Comment: вы в вопросе то напишите про `Iphone` и что баг на мобилках

Answer (score 3):

```css
*{
  margin:0;
}

#container1{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#container2{
    width: 100%;
    height: 99%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

html, body{
    height: 99%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow:hidden;
}

p{
  margin-bottom:300px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1">
  <div id="container2" >
    <p>Произвольный текст скрол вниз</p>
    <p>Произвольный текст скрол вниз</p>
    <p>Произвольный текст скрол вниз</p>
    <p>Произвольный текст скрол вниз</p>
    <p>Произвольный текст скрол вниз</p>
    <p>Произвольный текст скрол вниз</p>
    <p>Произвольный текст скрол вниз</p>
  </div>
<div>
```

---

```css
.element, .outer-container {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
}
 
.outer-container {
 border: 5px solid purple;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}
 
.inner-container {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}
 
.inner-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
 <div class="inner-container">
  <div class="element">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
   Integer vehicula quam nibh, eu tristique tellus dignissim
   quis. Integer condimentum ultrices elit ut mattis.
   Praesent rhoncus tortor metus, nec pellentesque enim
   mattis nec. Nulla vitae turpis ut dui consectetur
   pellentesque quis vel est. Curabitur rutrum, mauris ut
   mollis lobortis, sem est congue lectus, ut sodales nunc
   leo a libero. Cras quis sapien in mi fringilla tempus
   condimentum quis velit. Aliquam id aliquam arcu. Morbi
   tristique aliquam rutrum. Duis tincidunt, orci suscipit
   cursus molestie, purus nisi pharetra dui, tempor
   dignissim felis turpis in mi. Vivamus ullamcorper arcu
   sit amet mauris egestas egestas. Vestibulum turpis neque,
   condimentum a tincidunt quis, molestie vel justo. Sed
   molestie nunc dapibus arcu feugiat, ut sollicitudin metus
   sagittis. Aliquam a volutpat sem. Quisque id magna
   ultrices, lobortis dui eget, pretium libero. Curabitur
   aliquam in ante eu ultricies.
   
   Quisque vitae tincidunt purus. Vivamus feugiat bibendum
   erat, nec interdum urna porta sed. Nunc lobortis neque
   orci, ut suscipit nisl congue feugiat. Vivamus feugiat
   tellus quis cursus sollicitudin. Curabitur dolor massa,
   dictum ut ipsum in, porttitor pellentesque ante. Aenean
   egestas cursus tempor. Maecenas semper tortor sit amet
   egestas cursus. Mauris porttitor quis nisi ut tincidunt.
   Curabitur adipiscing eleifend nibh. Praesent mauris leo,
   consequat vitae orci eget, vestibulum bibendum nisi.
   Aliquam tempus diam ut tortor cursus, eget sodales augue
   adipiscing. Nulla at dignissim libero.
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

### Горизонтальная: (Update)

```js
$(function(){
  var curDown = false,
      curYPos = 0,
      curXPos = 0;
  $(".block").mousemove(function(m){
    if(curDown === true){
     $(".block").scrollTop($(".block").scrollTop() + (curYPos - m.pageY)); 
     $(".block").scrollLeft($(".block").scrollLeft() + (curXPos - m.pageX));
    }
  });
  
  $(".block_width_item").mousedown(function(m){
    curDown = true;
    curYPos = m.pageY;
    curXPos = m.pageX;
  });
  
  $(".block_width_item").mouseup(function(){
    curDown = false;
  });
})
```

```css
.block {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
 
.block::-webkit-scrollbar
{
   display: none;
}
 


.block_width {
    width: 1120px !important;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow: auto;
}

.block_width_item {
    width: 200px; 
}

*{ 
    user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <div class="block_width">
    <div class="block_width_item">Поиск</div>
    <div class="block_width_item">Новости</div>
    <div class="block_width_item">Видео</div>
    <div class="block_width_item">Изображение</div>
    <div class="block_width_item">Карта</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**jquery-ui.js**

```js
jQuery(".block_width").draggable({ 
    cursor: "move",  
    axis: "x",          
    stop: function() { 
      if(jQuery(this).position().left > 1 || jQuery(this).position().left < -800)
          jQuery(this).css("left", "10px");
    }
});
```

```css
.block {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
 
.block::-webkit-scrollbar
{
   display: none;
}
 
.block_width {
    width: 1120px !important;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow: auto;
}

.block_width_item {
    width: 200px; 
    cursor: pointer
}

*{ 
    user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 
    
<div class="block">
  <div class="block_width">
    <div class="block_width_item">Поиск</div>
    <div class="block_width_item">Новости</div>
    <div class="block_width_item">Видео</div>
    <div class="block_width_item">Изображение</div>
    <div class="block_width_item">Карта</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но первый вариант не работает почему-то.

Comment: @Predaytor нужна горизонтальная прокрутка без полосы скролла?

Comment: абсолютно верно, как в поисковике гугла. Вводишь что-то в поиск на мобилках и сверху список "Изображения Видео Новости и тд".

Comment: @Predaytor Понял, изи

Comment: так же как и было, иногда прокрутишь, очень редко, все как должно, в большинстве случаев полоса есть :(

Comment: @Predaytor обновил

Comment: Решено, это баг на айфонах :( Спасибо за ответы.